# Creating directory with space in name

Tags: shell, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory which has space in name e.g. `"user test"`
when I fire `mkdir -p "user test"` it works for me.

When I put `"user test"` in variable mkdir fails, it creates `"user` and `test"` separately

```
var="user test"
mkdir -p $var
```

I also tried `mkdir -p "$var"`

Can someone please suggest where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What happens when you do `mkdir -p "$var"` (which should be the correct syntax for POSIX shells or even better `mkdir -p -- "$var"`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)?

Comment: What's the shell? In `rc`, it should be `var='user test'; mkdir -p -- $var` as double quotes are not special in that shell and there's no implicit split+glob on unquoted variables like there is in Bourne-like shells.

Comment: Don't create directory with spaces in their name. Use an underscore `mkdir user_test`. It will be much easier after.

Comment: As a side note, I find certain attitude in answer and comment worrisome. Such "wisdom" exists because of sloppy scripts and programs written during earlier days. Instead of solving the artificial restriction, such attitude *encourages* the sloppy behavior to persist and spread. In the long run, one would need more time to troubleshoot why something doesn't work, or even causing trouble for others.

Comment: On what system and with which shell have you tried this? The normal `mkdir -p $var` should create 2 directories `user` and `test`, while `mkdir -p "$var"` should create only 1 dir `user test`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to escape the space

```
mkdir hello\ there
```

You can also encapsulate the string, this way you do not have to escape the space.

```
mkdir 'hello there'
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by ZN13 is correct. Just to provide more details -

You can do this by using an escape sequence (per-character escaping) such as a backslash ().

Example

```
mkdir Good\ Morning
```

Here, the backslash helps in escaping the space character before 'Morning'.

It is never recommended to use space in filenames, directories in Linux, because it makes data copying and other tasks associated with using filenames/directory names difficult.

Comment: It is, I just wanted to provide more details. I have acknowledged ZN13's response in my answer now.

Comment: Would you be specific at "It is never recommended to use space"? Is this due to the difficulty in search?

Comment: For example simple $* wont work the way you may think. In case >>>START>>>

for i in $*;
do
  echo $i;
done  <<<END<<<
Then this command: 
script.sh "a b" c "d e"  
will give you five lines instead of three. Each char in separate line. You'll need "$@" instead of $*